# phpmailer smtp issue

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

Recently changes were made to my server by my host regarding email due to spam.

> I have found that a large number of spam is being sent from your
>   server:
>
> root@server2 [~]# exiqgrep -r *************.com -c 5814 matches out
>   of 6122 messages
>
> This means that the *************.com is the recipient of 5,814
>   messages being sent from your server.  I have removed these messages
>   from the queue and increased the level of mail logging and security on
>   your server.  I have also disabled your server from being an open
>   relay, which appears to be how the mail was being sent out. There is a
>   good chance that this was causing the delay, however the issue remains
>   that you have a hijacked script/account that is trying to send mail at
>   this rate.  The server is now set to NOT send mail from any user other
>   than an SMTP user, root, and mailman;  As such you will have to ensure
>   that any mail scripts are properly using SMTP authentication.  You can
>   find more information on how to do so here:
>
> http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm
>
> I would also strongly suggest turning on DKIM and SPF records (which
>   can be done in cPanel under "Mail Authentication") for any and all
>   domains on this server as it will reduce the chance of
>   bouncebacks/rejected mail as well as being blacklisted for the spam
>   that has been going out. I am also running a malware scan on the
>   ************* account, and have turned off the default email address.  I
>   will let you know as soon as the scan is complete whether or not there
>   were any hits.

My scripts now have to use SMTP Authentication. Now I'm getting errors after updating my code.

> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in
>   /home/***/public_html/fkg/lib/phpmailer/class.SMTP.php on line 89
>
> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to
>   mail.***.**********.com:25 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: Name or service not known) in
>   /home/***/public_html/fkg/lib/phpmailer/class.SMTP.php on line 89
>   SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) Mailer Error
>
> Description: SMTP Error: could not connect to SMTP host server(s)

here is my code

```
$mail = new phpmailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "mail.***.************.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->Port = "25"; 
$mail->SMTPAuth  = true;   //we need to autenticate to the server
//$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  //we use ssl to protected the flow of info
$mail->Username = "noreply+*****.com"; //account 
$mail->Password = "********"; //password
```

any ideas on what is happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which library are you using as SMTP handler? i.e. what's `$mail`?

Comment: "Switch to SMTP" from what exactly?  You can't send mail without using SMTP.

Comment: Sorry everyone. Updated the question. Hopefully it makes it more clear. Different errors.

Comment: Have you tried sending on port 587 instead of 25? Typically 587 is used when authentication is needed - some servers and ISP will block outgoing email through port 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in the end of the day, after a long chat session...

Few issues. In this case, server on the other side was `exim`, which only allows you to authenticate after you hit it with an `EHLO` command. `PHPMailer`, that was used, doesn't allow you to force a `EHLO`, so authentication against `exim` server didn't work.

Switching to `PEAR::Mail` + `PEAR::Net_SMTP` + `PEAR::Net_Socket` "fixed" the issue.

References:

1. http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/download/
2. http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP/download
3. http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Socket/download

Comment: Thanks favoretti, I asked my host to do that now. I'll let you know if it fixes it.

Comment: They made the changes and now new errors have popped up. Updated Question.

Comment: Thanks again favoretti, silly mistake. Now the errors are similar to the original but slightly different. Updated the question.

Comment: We're back to square one, your host can not resolve your SMTP server's address. Try resolving it yourself and specify IP address instead of hostname for the `$mail->Host` and see if that alleviates your issue.

Comment: Ok, did that and got some different new errors. Sorry for all of the updates. I'm clueless on email stuff.

Comment: Ok, set debug to true, like `$mail->SMTPDebug = true;`, rather than `1`, and another option would be to ask it to use TLS, by adding `$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16335/discussion-between-favoretti-and-clint-chaney)

Comment: This is a bogus diagnosis. The SMTP spec [requires EHLO before AUTH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication), because the response from EHLO tells the client what kinds of AUTH are available, so exim is the same as all other servers in requiring this. Without that response, you have no idea how to authenticate with the server. PHPMailer handles this just fine (and also the repeated EHLO after STARTTLS), there's no need to 'force' anything. `SMTPDebug` is an integer value, not a boolean, so `$mail->SMTPDebug = true;` is incorrect.

Comment: @Synchro That's not true - go read the spec (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2821), especially the part about reading the spec and difference between SHOULD and MUST. Clients SHOULD send EHLO, so they are very much free to choose whether they want to send it or not. Regarding the SMTPDebug, in _his_ particular version there was no granularity from what I can remember, and even in the current version it's checked like: `if (!$this->SMTPDebug) { return; }`, so technically, it can be set to anything you like.

Comment: You mean like section 4.1.1.1 when it says "a client MUST issue HELO or EHLO before starting a mail transaction"? AUTH is an ESMTP extension, and so can only work if it is advertised via EHLO and thus can only occur *after* EHLO, so while it's true that you may sometimes use HELO instead of EHLO, you MUST use EHLO if you want to use AUTH, which is the case in this question. I think I know how `SMTPDebug` works, since I wrote it, and it acts differently with values of 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. That it may be tested by coercion to a boolean value does not mean that it IS a boolean value.

Comment: @Synchro: Yes, sure. MUST issue HELO `OR` EHLO. His issue was that PHPMailer was issuing HELO, no matter what. Don't get me wrong, I'm not trying to contest your knowledge of SMTPMailer, I'm just saying that in his particular case I wasn't able to make SMTPMailer actually issue a "oh-so-much-needed" EHLO. It was insisting on SMTP instead of ESMTP.

Comment: Well that's very strange since the code [always tries EHLO first](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php#L585) and it's worked that way [since 2003](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blame/master/changelog.md#L395), but I guess he could have had a really ancient version.